# Can the C# web driver be able to send data to the chrome snapshots?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, tabs

C# has a web driver that opens a tab and then enters the tabs. But he does this by walking around the tabs. I want all of the inputs to be the same. The code block I'm using does not support this.

```
lstWindow = driver.WindowHandles.ToList();    

foreach (var handle in lstWindow)
{
     driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);                     
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
}
```

This code is entered one by one by switching between bands. I want to login at the same time and instantly. Is it possible?

Comment: Short answer, yes it is possible...you can follow  the following tutorial http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/

Comment: Hello there,
I already use it. but I would like to have this process done at the same time on all the tabs. Unfortunately, there are tours between the places where you give them.
Thank you.